# How to crop the canvas to fit a specific area size in Fabric js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, crop

Among the functions of fabric js, there is a method or property that crops objects except canvas, but I did not find a function to crop the canvas itself. I tried changing the canvas to an image in the following way, cropping it, and then inserting it back into the canvas.

```
 fabric.Image.fromURL(canvas.toDataURL(), img => {
            currentImage = img; //save current canvas as image

            currentImage.set({
                scaleX : canvas.width / currentImage.width,
                scaleY : canvas.height / currentImage.height,
                cropX: selectionRect.left,
                cropY: selectionRect.top,
                width: selectionRect.getScaledWidth(),
                height: selectionRect.getScaledHeight(),

            });
            canvas.setDimensions({
                width: selectionRect.getScaledWidth(),
                height: selectionRect.getScaledHeight()
            });

            canvas.setBackgroundImage(currentImage).renderAll();
```

but in this case, an image with a transparent background becomes a background.

If you look at the following picture, a picture of a flower without a background is on the canvas, and What I want is to resize the canvas by the dotted rectangle area without making any objects on the canvas an image as follows.

before crop:

[image: before crop]

after crop:

[image: after crop]

Just as the starting range and area are determined with attributes such as `cropX` or `cropY` when cropping an object, I would like to know how to apply this to the canvas as well.